# In Database how to perform mathematical operations on table contents

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I have created a table in MYSQL

```
create table books2( 
    id varchar(4), 
    bookname varchar(20), 
    author varchar(30), 
    cost float);
```

and inserted the values as shown below...

```
insert into books2 values('bk1', 'learining', 'joseph', 350.49);
```

Now in need to perform `ceil()` operation on the cost how do I do that..

I tried

```
update 
  books2 
set 
  cost=ceil(select cost from books where id='b1.1') 
where 
  id='b1.1';
```

but its giving error "Missing expresssion"...

Comment: You have no column named `bid`, and no table named `book4` in your post. (You `CREATE TABLE` with `book2`, which does not have a column named `bid`, your `INSERT` references `book4`, and your `UPDATE` references `books`.) Therefore, your question makes absolutely no sense. Please [edit] to contain information that is consistent and actually matches your question. If you post nonsense, we can't help you.

Comment: The intent of the question is quite clear. I've corrected the inconsistencies.

Comment: Sorry Ken, My intention was clear. But messed up while posting the queries. Will be careful next time.

Comment: @Jim: I decided not to revert your edit because the poster responded quickly, but see [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101583) about editing code in questions.

Comment: @user2900314: Please read the last sentence of my original comment. Your "intention" being clear is an excuse. If you post nonsense, it's difficult to help you. It's *your responsibility* to provide accurate information if you want us to help you solve *your problem**. :-)

Comment: Ya, I understand will be careful next time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you operate within a single row you don't need to reselect the data:

```
update books 
    set cost=ceil(cost) 
where 
    bid='b1.1';
```

(ignoring the inconsistencies in your table names in the original question)

Comment: In this case the intent was clear regardless of the inconsistencies.

Comment: Sorry the mistake was not intended, I was trying various ways and jumbled up when posting the last query